# Looking for information on Information Theory applied to image pixelation

Tags: it.information-theory

I'm in seventh grade and am doing a science project about how age and gender affects people's ability to recognize pixelated images. For background research I have been reading about information theory and the general topic seems to be related to mine -- the entropy of pixelated images is lower than less pixelated images -- but all the stuff I can find really talks about communication channels and bandwidths.

I was wondering if you guys can offer some pointers to articles that deal with this connection. How I can measure the entropy change and what affect other information theory research has on impacting this issue.

I'm not asking you to do my homework for me, just looking for some papers and articles I can use to read up and educate myself, or some other pointers on how to pursue this topic.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good luck on your project!  Unfortunately I don't think information theory or theoretical computer science are going to be very useful or relevant to your project topic.  Instead, your topic seems more to do with the characteristics of humans and human perception (e.g., biology and cognitive science) rather than the mathematical properties of information.